# Posting array from Ajax to cshtml.cs using .NET Core

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using .NET Core and I am attempting to send an array from the `.cshtml` page via Ajax to the corresponding method. I have a strongly typed class that I wish the array to bind to but when the method is called, it returns null. I have managed to send simple data back (e.g. a single string) but anything like an array and it returns null.

This is the Ajax call and the array I am trying to send through.

```
var miniPediPrice = document.getElementById("MiniPedi").value * 1500;
    var miniPediDuration = parseFloat('@Model.miniPedi.Duration');
    const products = [{
        Name: '@Model.miniPedi.Name',
        Price: miniPediPrice.toString(),
        Duration: miniPediDuration.toString(),
        GelPolish: "false",
        NailArt: "false"
    }]


    console.log(products);
    const total = 0;
    try {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Products?handler=CalculatePrice",
            traditional: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(products),
            //data: JSON.stringify({ products: products }),
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#totalPrice").val(data)


            },
        });
    } catch (e) {

    }
```

The method that the ajax calls. The "products" is always null.

```
public IActionResult OnPostCalculatePrice([FromBody] List<Products> products)
{          
        var totalPrice = "";// product.Name;

        //TotalPrice = "£" + (totalPrice / 100).ToString();
        return new JsonResult(totalPrice);
}
```

Model class for Products:

```
public class Products
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Duration { get; set; }
    public bool GelPolish { get; set; }
    public bool NailArt { get; set; }

    public Products(string productName, decimal productPrice, decimal productDuration, bool gelPolish, bool nailArt)
    {
        Name = productName;
        Price = productPrice;
        Duration = productDuration;
        GelPolish = gelPolish;
        NailArt = nailArt;
    }
}
```

I have searched high and low for how to fix this but no luck. I am new to jQuery/Javascript so I am still learning syntax etc. I hope the information posted is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following steps to make it work.

1:Remove the constructor from your `produst`.

2:Change your ajax like(add `contentType: "application/json"` and  `decimal,bool` type no need to convert to string):

```
 var products =
        [{
            Name: "assad",
            Price: 12.5,
            Duration:4.5,
            GelPolish: false,
            NailArt: false
        }];

      $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Products?handler=CalculatePrice",
        traditional: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(products),
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#totalPrice").val(data)

        },
    });
```

3:Your action:

```
public IActionResult OnPostCalculatePrice([FromBody] List<Products> products)
{          
        var totalPrice = "";// product.Name;

        //TotalPrice = "£" + (totalPrice / 100).ToString();
        return new JsonResult(totalPrice);
}
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: Removing the constructor from products class made it work! Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you

1. Add 'contentType':'application/json'; in your ajax call.
2. Don't do JSON.stringfy.Directly use the products in data.
3. Remove the constructor from Products.cs class (It should be Product
   sinceyou are passing the array list to denote products)
4. Assign Price,duration **decimal value** and GelPoslish, NailArt boolean value (**boolean without quotes**.)

.